# Integration of the partial derivative

Tags: integration

I have two questions regarding solving  the integral of the partial. Here is the equation:

$$R_m = - \int \psi^m \frac{\partial}{\partial\psi} \left[\left(C_\phi \frac{\epsilon}{k} \left(\left\langle\phi\right\rangle - \psi \right) + S \left(\psi\right)\right)f_\phi \right] d\psi$$

where $f_\phi(\psi)$. I found in a book which re-write this equation as below (but the integration is between $-\infty$ and $\infty$):

$$R_m = m \int \psi^{m-1} \left[\left(C_\phi \frac{\epsilon}{k} \left(\left\langle\phi\right\rangle - \psi \right) + S \left(\psi\right)\right)f_\phi \right] d\psi$$

my first question is that how they get to the second definition from the first one and my second question is that does this hold for the integration between $0$ and $1$?

I appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably uses integration by parts, like
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f g'dx=\left.\left(f g\right)\right|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f' g dx
$$
with $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)g(x)=0$.